# The QN is ether 'n' or 'k' is negative method should return 'null' value. what did i missed?

Tags: java

//Write a function fill with signature

```
 int[] fill(int[] arr, int k, int n)
```

which does the following: It returns an integer array `arr2` of length n whose first k elements are the same as the first k elements of `arr`, and whose remaining elements consist of repeating blocks of the first k elements.  You can assume array `arr` has at least k elements. The function should return null if either k or n is not positive. 
Examples:

```
fill({1,2,3,5, 9, 12,-2,-1}, 3, 10) returns {1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1}. 
Fill({4, 2, -3, 12}, 1, 5)  returns {4, 4, 4, 4, 4}. 
fill({2, 6, 9, 0, -3}, 0, 4)
```

returns null value

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    int[] data = {1,2,3,5,9,12,-2,-1};

    int[] val = fill(data,3,10);  // calling function.

      for(int i=0;i< val.length; i++)
      {
        System.out.print(val[i]+" ");

      }

}
public static int[] fill(int[] arr, int k, int n) //method
{

    int[] arr2 = new int[n];
    int j=0;

    if(n<0 || k<0)
    {
        return null ;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<n ;i++)
    {
        arr2[i] = arr[j];

                j++;

            if(j>=k)
            {
                j=0;
            }
    }


  return arr2;

 }

}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: n and k aren't negative, what's your point?

Comment: if the value of n or k is 0 or negative the result should be null

Comment: when i pass the negative value for n or for k there is error "nullpointerexeption".